# Calling Worksheet_SelectionChange (Target) from inside Worksheet_Change (Target)

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to understand if it is possible to have a code like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Cells(6, 3).Value = "x" Then

       Worksheet_SelectionChange (Target)  

   end if

End sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox "Worksheet_SelectionChange"

End Sub
```

I'm receiving error :

Run time error "424" - Object required.

Please help me to understand

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Call Worksheet_SelectionChange(Target)
```

instead of just

```
Worksheet_SelectionChange(Target)
```